# nutch crawl does not use all entries in seed.txt

Tags: nutch, web-crawler

I am using apache-nutch-1.6 and I can successfuly crawl web sites.
My Problem is that not all entries in the seed.txt file are used. It depends on which sites are inside. So is there anywhere a Limit how much is crawled? No error message. Just if I delete one site an other sites is deeply crawled, whereever if the other one is there this one is crawled and from the other sites only the top sites I beleave....

Comment: 1) What is the exact command you are using to start the crawling? 2) ow many total links you are configuring in the Seed.txt file? 3) How many total number of pages you are expecting from all th elinks that you have mentioned in seed.txt file? 4) I guess the TopN parameter that you are giving is less that urls that you are getting that the crawl cycle....

Answer (score 0):

Configure this correctly:

```
bin/nutch crawl $URLS -dir $CRAWL_LOC -depth 10 -topN 1000
```

Depth: nutch will crawl upto this level in depth

topN: in each level, nutch will crawl this number of url's

Comment: What I do not understand: I have 3 Websites in seed.txt. If I use the command bin/nutch cralw URLs -dir crawl -depth 3 -topN 10 Only one Website is crawled.